# Error with association between two objects in two databases

Tags: java, ebean, playframework-2.6

I have following two classes:

**Company.java**

```
package models.kuno;

import io.ebean.Finder;
import io.ebean.Model;
import models.emil.Project;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = Company.TABLE_NAME)
public class Company extends Model {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "company";
    public static final Finder<Long, Company> find = new Finder<>(Company.class, "kuno");

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    public List<Project> projects;



    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Company() {
    }
}
```

**Project.java**

```
package models.emil;

import io.ebean.Finder;
import io.ebean.Model;
import models.kuno.Company;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = Project.TABLE_NAME)
public class Project extends Model {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "project";
    public static final Finder<Long, Project> find = new Finder<>(Project.class, "emil");

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String title;
    public int amount;


    @ManyToOne
    public Company company;



    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Project() {
    }
}
```

Both will be stored in separate databases. (Without the `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` it works like expected). But in this configuration it fails with following error:

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.emil.Project
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.<init>(EvolutionsModule.scala:20):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.emil.Project
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:88)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1250)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:746)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:360)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:154)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:142)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:46)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:107)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:66)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:409)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:404)
    at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.$anonfun$instanceOf$2(Injector.scala:117)
    at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.withContext(Injector.scala:126)
    at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.instanceOf(Injector.scala:117)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:185)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$reload$3(DevServerStart.scala:174)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:171)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.modelConversion(AkkaHttpServer.scala:183)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$24.onPush(Ops.scala:1191)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:512)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:475)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:371)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:584)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:468)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:559)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:741)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:756)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:666)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error with association to [class models.kuno.Company] from [models.emil.Project.company]. Is class models.kuno.Company registered?
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readManyToOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:168)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readAssocOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:54)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.parse(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:45)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:78)
    ... 88 more

2) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.emil.Project
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:32)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.emil.Project
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:88)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1250)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:746)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:360)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:154)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:142)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:46)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:107)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:66)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$3(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:49)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:38)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:185)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$reload$3(DevServerStart.scala:174)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:171)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.modelConversion(AkkaHttpServer.scala:183)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$24.onPush(Ops.scala:1191)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:512)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:475)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:371)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:584)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:468)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:559)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:741)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:756)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:666)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error with association to [class models.kuno.Company] from [models.emil.Project.company]. Is class models.kuno.Company registered?
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readManyToOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:168)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.readAssocOne(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:54)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocOnes.parse(AnnotationAssocOnes.java:45)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:78)
    ... 67 more

2 errors
```

**Project facts**

```
Play 2.6.11
sbt 1.0.4
scala 2.12.4
sbt-play-ebean 4.1.0
```

So where is my mistake with that mapping between `Company` and `Person`?

**application.conf**

```
play.evolutions {
    db.default.enabled = true
    db.kuno.enabled = true
    db.emil.enabled = true
}
ebean {
  kuno = ["models.kuno.*"]
  emil = ["models.emil.*"]
  default = ["models.changer.*"]
}
db {
  default {
    driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    logSql = true
    url = "mysql://***:***@127.0.0.1:3306/default?serverTimezone=CET&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false"
  }
  kuno {
    driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    logSql = true
    url = "mysql://***:***@127.0.0.1:3306/kuno?serverTimezone=CET&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false"
  }
  emil {
    driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    logSql = true
    url = "mysql://***:***@127.0.0.1:3306/emil?serverTimezone=CET&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled PlayEbean in `build.sbt`? Have you configured the models packages in the `application.conf`?

Comment: Yes I did. Without relationship it works fine.

Comment: Can you post the part of the `application.conf` where you registered the models

Answer (score 0):

When I need relationship between models I always specify the columns with the `@JoinColumn` annotation, in your example:

**Project.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "localColumnName", referencedColumnName = "foreignColumnName")
public Company company;
```